# Adding a function to onclick to close popup and refresh parent

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this save function below to submit a form, but i want to be able to add a function to the onclick to close the popup and refresh the parent once the form has submitted.

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="'.get_string('savechanges').'" 
onclick = "document.getElementById(\'submitform\').menuindex.value = document.getElementById(\'submitform\').grade.selectedIndex." />';

<script type="text/javascript">
function proceed(){
window.opener.location.reload(true);
window.close();
}
</script>
```

I have tried a few things with no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
​<div onclick="funcA(); funcB()">Click Me</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JavaScript:

```
function ​funcA(){
    alert(10);
}
function funcB(){
    alert(12)        
}​
```

To answer the question: use the `;` to separate different functions. In conclusion you can just type in javascript into the onclick, just mind to separate the statements by a `;`

**EDIT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function proceed(){
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
    }

    function inputClick(){
        var submitform = document.getElementById(\'submitform\');
        submitform.menuindex.value = submitform.grade.selectedIndex;
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="'.get_string('savechanges').'" 
    onclick = "inputClick(); proceed(); return false;" />';


</script>
```

Comment: Thans for the response, i have seen this and already tried it but it did not work How would i incorporate this into the above onclick?

Comment: I altered your example a little bit for better readability. In total I substracted your JavaScript code from the onclick to a function. I removed the last `.` from `grade.selectedIndex`. And, what I think was the problem all along, added a `return false` statement at the end. Without this statement the form submits like you'd suspect. But because you have JavaScript functions in it I don't assume you want this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have implemented the above and although the form is being submitted correctly it is still not refreshing the parent.

Comment: Try this code `var URL = unescape(window.opener.location.pathname);window.opener.location.href = URL; window.close();`  NOTE that I didn't test this.

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors? What browser are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

If the window is cross domain it will not work due to security.

Are you getting any errors?
Does the parent reload?
Does the popup close?

Personnaly I would avoid doing as you have due to popup blockers.  The best way I have found is using a fake html window with a iframe inside.

I have only used commercial versions of these most recent is compoent art here is a link to there demo of a html window.  http://aspnetajax.componentart.com/control-specific/dialog/features/core_features/webform1.aspx

I am sure there is are free libraries to do this though.

**EDIT**

I just noticed also that you have a ";" missing at the end of the line

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="'.get_string('savechanges').'"
onclick = "document.getElementById(\'submitform\').menuindex.value = document.getElementById(\'submitform\').grade.selectedIndex;" />';
```

Comment: thanks for the response. No errors, the popup opens and closes fine, the form submits fine, but the parent is not refreshing.

Comment: I did make an assumption the script section is been called on the page reload from the form submission?  Because you are using a submit input the click will submit the form it self as normal.  But for proceed to execute you need to be calling it at some point which you havn't shown in your code.  It would be worth placing an alert("proceed") in the code to ensure it is been called.